# MySQL/PHP adding new column in PHP output after new value in column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

apologize if there is already answer for that, but as a newbie to I'm not able to recognize one.

I have a trouble with outputing data from MySQL.
Imagine a table "visits" in MySQL:

```
1. name------surname------date------visitTime
2. John        White        20111017  13:00
3. John        White        20111017  17:00
4. John        White        20111017  19:00
5. John        White        20111018  07:00
6. Jack        Black        20111017  09:00
7. Jack        Black        20111018  16:00
```

I would like to have number of visits sumarized by date and printed out on the php page like this

```
1. name surname 20111017 20111018 ----> other days
2. John White   3        1
3. Jack Black   1        1
```

the query I'm using so far is

```
$query = "select name,surname,count(*) as visitCount
          from visits group by name,surname,date";
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Try googling for pivot table mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to do it like that.  Like KA_lin said this could get very very ugly as you get more and more different visit days.

A cleaner solution would be to group the data with this query.
"**select name, surname, date, count(date) 
from visits
group by name, surname, date;**"

name  surname      date          visitCount

Jack    Black      20111017     1

Jack    Black      20111018     1

John    White     20111017     3

John    White     20111018     1

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger on insert(your table) (increment the value of a colomn visit_number if new, else insert), you can have a log for each visit(current table) and another table with the number, so that you won`t have to query by COUNT(), imagine 1 milion visits...

Comment: hmmm, thanx a lot, but I have to say the table is just an example. My problem is how to get in php every new date(day) in a new column on php page

Comment: can you rephrase please, i don`t understand